# APIs from Community/Site are running longer after deployment or code change

Tags: apex, community, api, customer-portal

The API calls from Community/Site takes about 10-14 secs on average to complete and return a response to portal.

But there are times when it takes more than 50 secs when same input is being passed to the API. We observed this usually happens right after deployment, after change in API, or while running the API for first time in the day.
Recently, we noticed that APIs are running longer for no specific reason. This is leading to bad user experience.
However, this only happens when the API is called for the first time in a long time or after code change. Rest of the time, API calls work seamlessly.

What could be the root for this? How to solve it? What is it's possibility to take place in production?

Comment: Sounds like a compilation/system caching issue on the platform. One fix is to periodically invoke your API from a "non-user" thread to keep the internal system caching alive.

Comment: It may be an SOQL optimization issue, against a large table, and you might need Salesforce to set up a skinny table to help with this.

Comment: I see the same issue. API calls takes longer sometime to complete and return response and sometimes it runs fast and smooth. How can I resolve this?